# node js not working with SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, started learning node.js and tried the most basic thing in the world: A "Hello World" from the server.

the code is the following (copied from an actual book):

```
var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

I hit the `node.js` executable, type `node server.js` and gives the famous `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.

Tried looking for similar questions but couldn't find something that would help something as simple as what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: The code itself looks correct. Usually SyntaxErrors are due to typos, but I have copied and pasted your code and verified it works. Could be an environment issue?

Comment: You run `node server.js` from the command line, not inside the node REPL

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference between the command line and the node.js shell?

Answer (score 1):

The [`node REPL`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) aka node shell, the REPL provides a way to interactively run `JavaScript` and see the results. It can be used for debugging, testing, or just trying things out. Here is one good [how-to-use-nodejs-repl](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/REPL/how-to-use-nodejs-repl)

Whereas, the command line is used to run the node command like `node server.js`.

You run `node server.js` in command line.

Comment: Seriously, I can't understand the difference between the console shell and the ''command line''. I thought it was the same thing.

Comment: @HiagoSerpa, the command line could run the command like `node` or other script file or the commands could be searched by `Path` environment. If you run `node` in command line, the Node REPL will come up, same as hit the `node.js` executable. which is `Javascript interpreter`, you can run javascript code in the REPL. Hope I make myself clearly...

Comment: I'm feeling mentally challenged here lol, So what should I do, apart from opening nodejs.exe and typing 'node server.js'?

Comment: We have all been there! You dont want to open node.exe! At least not now.  In windows(8 or 10) you can right-click the windows button and choose `command prompt`.  After that typing `node server.js` will run server.js using node.  --- The difference is the same as if you were to open node.exe by double clicking versus dropping a file (`server.js`) on node.exe. (Except that the window will close really quickly, so opening the OS command line first is so we can see what is happening.) You can also shift-right-click a folder and choose `"open a command window here"`.

Comment: @HiagoSerpa, `ippi` give you the right way to how to run. another way to click `Run` after click the window button, then input `cmd` in the `run dialog`, then OK, the command line will come up, and go to the right folder to run `node server.js`...

Comment: Alternately, if you have already run `nodejs.exe`, you can type `require('/my/program/path/server.js')` instead.